# How to model breakdowns of transporters (in a transporter fleet)?

Tags: anylogic

I want to model breakdowns of a Transporter (using the TransporterFleet). When breaking down, the transporter should stop its movements, and go on moving when repaired.

I found the function "Agent.stop()" to stop the movement.
Are you aware of a function like "goOn() / resumeMovement()"... ?

Is there another best practise, how to model breakdowns of transporters?

Thanks and happy homeofficing!

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial answer:
To stop (breakdown) a transporter temporarily it is possible to set the maximum speed to 0. After the breakdown the original maximum speed can be set again.

> Transporter.setMaximumSpeed(double speed, SpeedUnits units)

Warning: This can cause internal Anylogic Errors when using version < 8.5.2